# JAVA: Partitioning list of user objects on a condition using Stream API and convert to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, collectors

I have a class Agent, which has following members:

```
class Agent{ 
   String name;
   long funds;
   //... getters and setters, parameterized constructor
}
```

Now, I have a list of Agent class objects.

```
ArrayList<Agent> listAgents=new ArrayList<Agent>();
```

I want to give stars to the top performers, like 5 star for someone who has funds of more than 100000, 4 stars to someone with fund of 80000, and so on.

> I want to store this record in Map<String,String> like
> <ABC,*****> <PQR,****>

I tried the following code:

```
Map<String,String> star=listAgents
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(agn->giveStars(agn.getGeneratedFund())));
```

Here giveStars is function defined as below:

```
public static String giveStars(long generatedFund) {
        if(generatedFund>=100000)
            return "*****";
        else if(generatedFund<100000&& generatedFund>=80000)
            return "****";
        else if(generatedFund<80000 && generatedFund>=60000)
            return "***";
        return "";
}
```

This didn't work. Also, I don't think this is the right way to do this.
How to do this using Stream API's functions?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You give 5 stars for just 100K+ so it always return first, the condition for 4 stars is never true (the same number less than 100K and over 800K), so 5 stars should be given for 1M+.  It's better to use underscore in large numbers to separate thousands: `1_000_000`, `800_000` etc.

Comment: @Alex Rudenko Thank you for replying and your suggestion about the underscore concept. The figures were just for demo. Sorry for the confusion. In actual, that group by wasn't giving the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming <ABC,*****> <PQR,****> means you have a map of agent name to its star rating, you don't want grouping, you want to map your existing items to different ones.

Here's one way how:

```
Map<String,String> star = listAgents.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Agent::getName, agn->giveStars(agn.getGeneratedFund())));
```

If you group items, you don't change them but assign to different groups (doh). Mapping is a process where you change an object to be something different.

Comment: I am getting this error: 
Type Mismatch:cannot convert from Map<String,Object> to HashMap<String,String>

Comment: @Yash you're using some other code then what you have in the question? There is no HashMap<String,String> in the question, you have Map<String,String> there

Comment: Sorry, I had used HashMap<String,String>. I changed it to Map<String,String>. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is an issue in the method `giveStars` which should be rewritten:

```java
public static String giveStars(long generatedFund) {
    if (generatedFund >= 1_000_000)
        return "*****";
    else if (generatedFund >=800_000)
        return "****";
    else if (generatedFund >= 600_000)
        return "***";
    return "";
}
```

Next, the code `Collectors.groupingBy(agn->giveStars(agn.getGeneratedFund()))` contradicts the intention to have a map `Map<String, String>` - it will create `Map<String, List<Agent>>` where the key is the star rating.  So maybe your *real* intention is to change the type of the map.

```java
Map<String, List<Agent>> groupByStars = listAgents.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(agent -> giveStars(agent.getGeneratedFund())));
```

Such map will let to get top agents immediately.

If `Map<String, String>` (agent name to stars rating) is required, `toMap` collector may be used as suggested earlier, but this would work only if agent names are unique.  If some duplicate values may occur, a merge function is required (e.g. to keep the agent with a better rating):

```java
Map<String, String> groupByAgentName = listAgents.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Agent::getName, 
            agent -> giveStars(agent.getGeneratedFund()),
            (rating1, rating2) -> rating1.length() > rating2.length() ? rating1 : rating2,
            LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
        ));
```

Comment: I have rewritten the giveStars function. I want the final output as Map<String,String>. I tried your approach for this. But this results in the error, "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,Object> to Map<String,String>"

Comment: The error clearly shows that `giveStars` returns `Object` instead of `String` after you changed `giveStars` function (so the accepted answer has the same "issue" as you mentioned in the comment)